# Script Editor crashing when running Applescript

Tags: applescript, contacts, crash

I need to extract the phone number of all the contacts in a particular group and for that I am using the following code -

```
on run {input, parameters}  
    tell application "Contacts"
        set thePeople to every person
        repeat with i from 1 to number of items in thePeople
            set this_person to item i of thePeople
            set inGroup to name of group of this_person
            if inGroup is "Technology" then
                set x to properties of phones of this_person
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
end run
```

But whenever I run the code, the script editor crashes and asks me to reopen it even though I have only one contact in that group. What's happening here?

Comment: did you test it with 'try' just to see if the behaviour is different?

Comment: Can you elaborate? I am new to AppleScript. +Tetsujin

Comment: you can isolate any part of an applescript so it attempts & doesn't error if it fails. Similar syntax to an if/end if, starts 'try' ends with 'end try'. Anything in between won't halt on error. May not work, but might allow you to hone down the problem section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
tell application "Contacts"
    set inGroup to first group whose name = "Technology"
    set phoneProps to properties of phones of inGroup's people
end tell
```

Comment: How do I retrieve only the phone number as an output instead of the label, class etc.

Comment: set phoneProps to value of phones of inGroup's people

Comment: is the result a string? @aday

Comment: No, a list of lists.

Comment: The element inside the lists? What type?

Comment: The value itself is a string